# what does "/a" in batch file means?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

set numberOfThreads= %1 
set portNumberToStart = %2
echo step1 %numberOfThreads%
:loop
if %numberOfThreads%==0 (goto :eof) else (start node . portNumberToStart)
set /a numberOfThreads=%numberOfThreads%-1
echo loop %numberOfThreads%
goto :loop
```

What does the "/a" means? when i remove "/a" the numberOfThreads will be set to -1

Answer (score 0):

To quote `SET /?`:

> The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
>   is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
>   is pretty simple and supports the following operations, in decreasing
>   order of precedence:
>
> ()                  - grouping
>      ! ~ -               - unary operators
>      * / %               - arithmetic operators
>      + -                 - arithmetic operators
>      << >>               - logical shift
>      &                   - bitwise and
>      ^                   - bitwise exclusive or
>      |                   - bitwise or
>      = *= /= %= += -=    - assignment
>        &= ^= |= <<= >>=
>      ,                   - expression separator

Answer (score 0):

The /A is a parameter switch being given to `set` command. If you type `help set` at a command prompt you will see the following (amongst other useful info):

> The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
>   is a numerical expression that is evaluated.